# Tumblr Themes : ul, il spacing issues?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I am in the process of creating a Tumblr theme to work on my CSS and HTML abilities and I have run into a problem.

http://cl.ly/3c0q3X3a0A193z1u2u2V - photo post

http://cl.ly/3V3R1W2h17100g371W2y - text post

As you can see from the picture above, the text seems to scoot itself down without any other code versus the photo which is always in the correct location.

I am still in my infancy whenever it comes to this kind of thing so I'm not really sure what to do.

Here's my CSS and HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<ul class="header">
    <li><a href="/"><h1>{Title}</h1></a>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a>
    <li><a href="/message">Message</a>
    <li><a href="/archive">Archive</a>
</ul>

<ul class="content">
    {block:Posts}
    {block:Text}
        <li class="text_post">
            {block:Title}
                    <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                {/block:Title}
            {Body}
        </li>
    {/block:Text}
    {block:Photo}
        <li class="photo_post">
            <img src="{PhotoURL-500}">
        </li>
    {/block:Photo}
{/block:Posts}
</ul>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family:Georgia, times, serif; 
    font-size:0.7em;}
h1 {
    display:inline;
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
    color:#00C462; }
ul, ol {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;}
.header {
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:1em;}
.header li {
    float:left;
    padding-left:1em;}
.header li a, a:visited {
    color:#000000;
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;}
.header li a:hover {
    color:#CCCCCC;}
.content {
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-top:1.3em;
    width:500px;
    margin-left:23em;}
</style>
```

Also, if you have any suggestions on how I can improve my code, please share.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Could you provide a link to the page? I have a hunch, but would like to inspect code; the screenshots alone won’t cut it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are just missing a width on .header...

The .content ul should then float up nicely next to it.

You just have to calculate the contents of your container. eg...

```
#container {
    width:800px; for example
    }
.header {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    }
.content {
    width:500px;
    float:left;
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

First, explicitly set your **h3**'s **margin** and **padding** to 0. Then write appropriate rules to add margin/padding to the bottom of the h3.

Second, why are you not floating the header & content classes to left & right respectively? Here's a link to a theme that I'm working on- [El Aleph](http://tinkererof.tumblr.com/). I'm doing something similar with my blog title and content. I've just floated my title to left and my content to right. Feel free to take a look at my theme's CSS.

Also, why are you using ULs for block level content? The best way is to either use DIVs for dividing blocks of content or use HTML5 elements such as header, article, etc.